# Facebook share button issue

Tags: facebook, button, share

I added the facebook share button within an email body (.htm). The purpose of the button is to share the photo a user received in his email. When the button is clicked, a new tab opens with the "Write a message" area to share on facebook.
The problem is that once "Share Link" button is clicked nothing happens - no confirmation, no redirect, BUT the link is actually posted on Facebook (so the end user would not know the message has been shared unless they check their Facebook while all confused). Here is the code for the button:

```
<a title="Share this photo" 
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
    s=100
&p[url]=%PHOTO_LINK%.jpg (dynamically populated link)
&p[title]=Check out my pic!"
target="_blank">
<img src="someplace.png" 
alt="Share on Facebook" height="50" width="50" />
</a>
```

I have tried using meta tags (title/description/url and the main namespace tag), but they are not picked up when shared (title/description is a bunch of random characters). Is this behaviour normal for share buttons of this sort, is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, put `target="_blank"` in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: It already contains `target="_blank"`.  See: `<a title="Share this photo" ... target="_blank">`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to share a photo within an email as it would mean sharing the URL to the email itself (which users won't have access to).

Instead, you should put the image on a website and use OpenGraph markup to give it a correct title, description, and thumbnail image. And then share the URL to this image on Facebook. You can still embed the image in the email, but the sharing and image need to be external from the email.

Comment: It totally works. When an email is received and the facebook image link is clicked, it does take me to the "Share this link" page and I can write a comment, title shows up properly, correct photo link is present. However, once "Share Link" button is clicked nothing happens, while the message is actually posted on Facebook's wall (on one computer the tab actually closes after sharing, but on another it persists).

Comment: Basically everything works as intended except the confirmation of the shared/posted link is missing which is missleading to the end user.

Comment: That could be a facebook issue causing the popup to close early. You can always show a confirmation yourself as FB return the `post_id` if successfully posted.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has happened since 2012.  There are now two API's a user may choose from when sharing on Facebook: 1) Sharer, and 2) Share Dialog.

**Sharer**: This will require confirmation of the user posting their content, and this will then get you what you want.  However, Sharer *only supports the `url` parameter now.*  There is basically no way to share any other parameter.  **[Official Facebook Developer Docs: Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)**.  And: **[Official Facebook Discontinuation of Sharer Non-URL Args Post](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/357750474364812/)**.

**Share Dialog**: You will need to configure an App with Facebook, authenticate, and then to solve your problem, you'll want to set one of these params...

- `display` : Set this to `page` (the default), or one of the other options, to determine how your share dialog displays.
- `redirect_uri` : If you don't like how Facebook decides to interpret your `display` params, you can just redirect *after sharing* to some page on your site that says, "Post successfully shared! *link to post*" or some such.

Hope this helps someone.